# Is there a way to create a folder-specific readme file in github?

Tags: github

Github parses and displays a readme.txt or readme.md file at the root of the repository.

I would like to create a similar readme file for a particular folder. Is there a way to accomplish this?

<s>One ugly hack I thought of was to name the file _readmeme.md causing it to appear as the first file in the folder, and making it easy for users to find and click it.</s> - it doesn't work, _README appears **last** and not first.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

GitHub already has this feature.  Just put your README file in a subdirectory, and it will be displayed just like one in the root directory.

For example, see README.md for this subdirectory:
http://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/lbForth/tree/master/targets

Comment: Heh, I tried it but had a spelling mistake in the _name_ of the readme file, so it didn't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: What if there is more than one subdirectory with a `README` file in it? How does one specify which subdirectory's `README` is supposed to appear at the "root"?

Comment: @Tfovid, only the root README will show when you view the top directory.  Only the subdirectory README will show when you look at that subdirectory.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I just tried that works is use the .md extension on the README file, so README.md and github is smart enough to display it using markdown (way better than plain text).

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't display using the ".md" extension. Does this work for you still?

Comment: Mine doesn't work at all either way. Either the feature has been removed or does not work on private repos or something

Comment: I can confirm it works. Just that it only works two levels deep and not three. Using the .md is also much nicer.