# Configure github to use some other file as README

Tags: github

Because of how Eclipse and EGit organize files and directories, I have my README.md file not in the root directory of my git repository but one folder deeper. How can I tell github to show `some_folder/README.md` as project's readme?

Comment: This is the same question as this one:

[Create a folder-specific read me file in GitHub][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020891/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-folder-specific-readme-file-in-github

Comment: No, it's not. I already have README.md in some non-root folder and it shows up as readme for that folder, but I want it to be used as readme for the whole project.

Answer (score 6):

- In the root directory of your repo, create a folder named `.github`.
- Create a file named `README.md` in this folder.
- Save the relative path of the file you want to use as the repo README in `.github/README.md`.

This causes `README.md` to be interpreted as a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (symlink) file.

Example:

- [This repo](https://github.com/Chomenor/ioef-cmod/tree/6724f3cdbdc64f79e2e5ab169efb867de02e5155) has files named `README.md` and `cmod-readme.md` in its root directory. Normally the former would be used as the README shown on the repo's main page, but instead the latter is used.
- The repo contains [a `.github/README.md` file](https://github.com/Chomenor/ioef-cmod/blob/6724f3cdbdc64f79e2e5ab169efb867de02e5155/.github/README.md), which contains the relative path to `cmod-readme.md`, i.e., `../cmod-readme.md`.

The fact that GitHub will follow symlinks when locating a repo's README doesn't seem to be documented, although the `.github` folder is mentioned on [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-readmes) in GitHub's docs:

> If you put your README file in your repository's root, `docs`, or hidden `.github` directory, GitHub will recognize and automatically surface your README to repository visitors.

It's also interesting that (based on the example repo linked above) GitHub apparently prioritizes the `README.md` file in `.github` over a file of the same name in the repository's root.

Comment: This is not an accurate description of how to create symlinks.  [This answer on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981731/208273) explains it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to do it for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981731/7452130

Github wouldn't interpret my `.github/README.md` file as a symlink unless I created a symlink on my system and then pushed it.