# eclipse show README from root

Tags: eclipse

It's not uncommon to have the following structure of projects:

- projectA - directory
- projectB - directory
- projectX - directory
- CHANGELOG - file
- LICENSE - file
- README - file

This structure (the fact that README is located in the root directory) is supported well by different online Git solutions (like github.com, bitbucket.org).

How can we make Eclipse import CHANGELOG, LICENSE, README files from the root of repository and show them in Project Explored/Navigator?

(a similar question was asked [Configure github to use some other file as README](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656932/configure-github-to-use-some-other-file-as-readme) but its goal was to make online tool render a README from subdirectory. I'm insterested in the opposite: Eclipse showing the README, ...)

Comment: Everything in an Eclipse workspace has to be in a project so you can't do this.

Comment: The correct answer was kindly provided by @howlger. It IS possible to do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `README.md`:

1. **Right-click a project** and choose ***New > File***
2. In the *New File* dialog:

   1. Click ***Advanced >>***
   2. Check ***Link to file in the file system***
   3. Enter **`PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/README.md`**
   4. Click ***Finish***

Note, these files are shown in the ***Git Repositories*** view below the ***Working Tree*** node. Instead of using the trick described above, just open these files via the *Git Repositories* and then edit, save and commit them as usual.