# How to get Eclipse Variables project specific

Tags: java, eclipse

I manage to define variables to be used as part of a classpath.
But they are always containing absolute path information.

Now I read, that such variables can be project or workspace specific.
[(see here)](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm)

(But following the How-To, I always produce general variables, valid for the whole workspace)

---

edit:
My projects have a couple of links like REPOSITORY/org/springframework/....jar

REPOSITORY is a variable referring to an absolute path.

I have different versions of these paths and want to easily switch a project from one version to another. If resolving the variable were project specific, it were super easy.

---

Questions:

- how do I define project specific variables?
- is there a difference between classpath variables and others?
- is there a way to define Variables relative to a project root path? (in that case, the variable could eventually even be workspace wide, resulting in the same subfolder relative to the project)
- Is defining two Variables REPOSITORY_A and REPOSITORY_B and editing the project classpaths to use one of them, the only way?

(BTW: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen3 4.7.3 and want to link to different repository version, depending on the project version)

Comment: What problem does a project-specific variable help solve?

Comment: What do you want to use the variables for? In case of linked files/folders see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651777/6505250

Comment: One group of projects takes libraries from Version A repository, Another group works with a different version of that repository. (See the edit of my question)