# Specify alternate project-level README.md on GitHub

Tags: github, readme

Using GitHub's web-based interface I cannot figure out how to specify an alternate path / filename for the project's README file.

When creating a new README, the web interface does give me the option of using any arbitrary path or filename I want, but the file I select is not used as the project-level README. I would like it to be displayed when users visit the project page.

In the context of projects that are modules or extensions (e.g. Magento 1 modules) having all such README files at `/README.md` for all such projects would make them all get over-written in the final merge, so an alternate path or filename should be used (e.g. `/docs/projectname/README.md` or `/projectname.md`).

How can I do this in a way that specifies that file as the default README?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

GitHub [looks for `README` files in a few places](https://help.github.com/articles/about-readmes/):

> If you put your README file in your repository's root, `docs`, or hidden `.github` directory, GitHub will recognize and automatically surface your README to repository visitors.

If you want to use another file for your project-level `README` I suggest creating a hidden `.github/` directory and [symlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) your file there with a name GitHub expects.

- On Linux or macOS this should be fairly straightforward:

  ```sh
    # From your repository root
    mkdir .github
    cd .github
    ln -s ../docs/projectname/some-README.md README.md
  ```
- On Windows things are a bit trickier.

  Symbolic links are only available on NTFS filesystems on Windows Vista or later, and creating them requires [special rights or Developer Mode](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/). They are [not supported by Git on Windows out of the box](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links).

  In your Git shell, in the root directory of your repository, enable symlinks for the current repo:

  ```sh
    git config core.symlinks true
  ```

  Now run `cmd.exe` as administrator¹ and `cd` to the repository root. Make your symlink:

  ```sh
    mkdir .github
    cd .github
    mklink README.md ..\docs\projectname\some-README.md
  ```

  Note that the name of the link goes *before* the name of the real file here, in contrast with the Linux and macOS instructions above. You can close `cmd.exe` now and go back to Git Bash.

Now commit `.github/README.md` and push to GitHub. You'll probably want to make sure that there isn't a real `README` file in any of the other locations GitHub uses (the repository root or a `docs/` folder in the repository root).

Windows users who clone the repository won't get a symlink automatically. If they wish to have that behaviour they should clone with a special argument:

```sh
git clone -c core.symlinks=true <repo-url>
```

---

¹It's possible to grant `mklink` permissions to non-admin users, but running as administrator is likely the simplest solution.

Comment: @Chris But it happens to me that then the resources like images don't show in Github because it's like it expects to find them in the directory where the symlink is, instead of in the directory where the real .md file is...  which kinda makes sense? But does anyone know if there is a workaround or whatever? The idea is these resources be only placed along the real .md for convenience, but still show correctly no matter from where, of course....

Comment: @Rai, you still have the option to put all documentation files, including images, in a `docs/` directory or in `.github/`. (Symlinking directories doesn't seem to work. You could symlink every single file, but that'd be a maintenance nightmare... I suggest you just pick `docs/` and be done with it.)

Comment: @Chris So finally the problem might simply be Githunb and symlinked directories don't get along after all... And I racking my brains doing all kinds of tests . Anyway, although that's unfortunate, thank you so much for letting me know, since I didn't get an answer to [my formal question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77973339/2805176) and, although I ended up going for a different (less practice, though) approach, I never knew for sure what could be really failing there, since I kinda assumed that if file symlinks worked, directory ones should work as well, but there it is...