# Rename README.md to custom name and use as a project description

Tags: github, bitbucket, readme

I do apologize if similar question already put, but I haven't found one.

I would like to change the default project description file name (called `README.md`) to be a custom name (let's say `XXX.md`) and I wonder if it is possible to be the `XXX.md` the initial readme file for the project (typical situation: you open the project Code page and you will see the content of `XXX.md` down at bottom).

I would like to verify if this approach possible in general, but I am mainly interested in Github and Bitbucket services. I briefly checked project settings and I cannot find there such customization. Is it even possible?

Comment: For GitHub, you can softlink a `/.github/README.md` to your `XXX.md`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981731/3775493

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub, at least, doesn't provide the ability to do this.  It is possible to use a different format (e.g., `README.asciidoc` or `README.rst`), but the root file must be called `README`.

Note that you can include other text markup documents like this and they'll be rendered if they're visited, it's just that they won't appear at the bottom of the file listing like a README will.

Comment: Looks like Bitbucket uses same approach ( https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/readme-content/ )