# Why Github could be not showing my symliked README's images?

Tags: github, resources, symlink, readme

For convenience, I have had to move my README file (in this case *README.htm*) to my own directory and symlink it from .github folder as *README.md* in order it's recognized by Github. Well, even though I'm aware it kind of differs to the norm, everything seems to work as expected as you can see...

- [https://github.com/lost-scripts/ls_readme_1](https://github.com/lost-scripts/ls_readme_test)

...and the README is indeed found and showed by Github as expected. BUT, as you also can see, it doesn't seem to be able to "find" the images and therefore they are not loaded, even though the "Resources" symlink follows the same logic and everything points where it should. I've to use "local" relative paths to the actual items/resources cause the user should be able to open *README.htm* file locally and offline.

Any idea why Github deals correctly with the symlink to *README.htm* but not with the symlink to *Resources* folder or its contents? It seems it just should work... Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

```
![alt text](http://url/to/img.png)
```

Try this markdown
I think you can link directly to the raw version of an image if it's stored in your repository.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention the _README.htm_ file has to work also when user open it locally and offline, so links to images/resources can't point to a web direction but to its relative paths.