# How to create README file inside sub-directory on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to create a README file in a subdirectory on GitHub. I only see the **Add a README** button when I am in the root directory. It is not visible in subdirectories.
Is there any way I can add a README file in a subdirectory and preview it?

Comment: Yes, you can.On GitHub then every folder will have then a different README.

Comment: Have a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020891/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-folder-specific-readme-file-in-github)

Comment: but how . i don't find the button to create it

Comment: Have a look at Microsoft new documentation repos on github, They use some interesting things like ![INCLUDE] . Though I am not sure it is extension of Github's markdown or not.

Comment: @URoy:  https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/contributor-guide/custom-markdown-extensions.md

Comment: But the simplest, most natural way - just create wiki pages in your github project. Refer it in the root readme. A more complicated way - create a docum site on github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a folder-specific readme file in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020891/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-folder-specific-readme-file-in-github)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Go to the directory [image: directory browsing on GitHub].
2. Create a new file [image: GitHub file creation button]
3. Name it as README.md [image: entering file name for a new file on GitHub]
4. Commit change
5. You can see the README in the subdirectory [image: Markdown preview of README.md on GitHub]

Answer (score 4):

There is no button to create a README on the GitHub web interface in any folder but the root. If you want to add a README to another folder, you can navigate to that folder and press the "Create new file" button. Just name the file `README.md` and you'll have the exact same editor available.